# BS4 Web scraping in Python loop is just showing last value not the entire 21

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I am still newbie. If run the python file in the console, it gives me only last headline of the entire 21 and I don't know why my loop isn't working...

'''

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url='https://www.ingenieur.de/fachmedien/bauingenieur/'

#opening up connection grabbing the page
uClient = urlopen(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#page parsing 
page_soup=soup(page_html, "html.parser")



#Grabs each headline
teasers=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"ing-teaser"})

**for teaser in teasers:
    headline = teaser.div.img["alt"]**


print("Headlines:" + headline)
```

'''

Comment: your `print` statement isn't in the loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So in python indentation is imperative. It's not a choice. If you want the print statement to print in every iteration on the loop you have to align it under `headline = teaser.div.img["alt"]`